# Orion Context Broker v2 subscription issue

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

We're trying to implement subscriptions with Orion Context Broker v2, but when we create a new subscription it's returning a '405 Method Not Allowed' response.

We're following the documentation (http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/), I've attached an image with the request sent with Postman:

[Postman subscription request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGfUZ.png)

The Orion Context Broker version we are using is:

```
{
  "orion": {
    "version": "0.25.0",
    "uptime": "16 d, 23 h, 49 m, 31 s",
    "git_hash": "a8cf800d4e9fdd7b4293a886490c40309a5bb58c",
    "compile_time": "Mon Nov 2 09:13:05 CET 2015",
    "compiled_by": "fermin",
    "compiled_in": "centollo"
  }
}
```

Are we doing something bad related with the request?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NGSIv2 operations to create/update/delete subscriptions have not been yet implememented in Orion 0.26.1 (the last version at the moment of writting this). The NGSIv2 operations related with subscriptions available in that version are:

- `GET /v2/subscriptions`, to get all subscriptions
- `GET /v2/subscripstions/<id>`, to get a given subscription (by id).

Note that NGSIv2 is yet in beta status, so sometimes the specification goes ahead of Orion implementation. Please, have a look to [the following table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f4m624nmO3jRjNalGE11lFLQixnfCENMV6dc54wUCCg/edit#gid=50130961) in order to know the current implementation status of the different operations described at the [NGSIv2 draft specification](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/). This table is updated in a monthly basics.

**EDIT**: NGSIv2 operations to create/update/delete subscription are available from Orion 0.27.0.

Comment: Thanks @fgalan, we will use NGSIv1 for the subscriptions then.

Comment: Finally, NGSIv2 subscription create/update/delete operations will be available for Orion 0.27.0 release (to be released at the end of January 2016). Answer has been edited to included that information.